# Nesting a list in a value for dictionary

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to make a code that sorts a bunch of cities into groups based on their temperature on a specific day. A group is made by increments of 5 celsius that start from 0. So from 0 to (but excluding) 5, this is group 1, from 5 to (but excluding 10) is called group 2.
I'm not sure of how to fix it, could someone point me in the right direction please?

My code so far:

```
cities_per_temp_bin = {} #K is bin, V is city
is_first_line = True
city = []
for row in open("climate_data_Dec2017.csv"):
  if is_first_line:
    is_first_line = False
  else:
    values = row.split(",")
    date = values[0]
    if date == "2017-12-25":
      cities = values[2].split()
      temp = float(values[5])
      group = int(temp//5)
      for line in cities:
        city.append(cities)
        if city not in group: #Error: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
        cities_per_temp_bin = city
          
      
for key in sorted(cities_per_temp_bin):
  print(key, ":", sorted(cities_per_temp_bin[key]))
```

Comment: Python's `list` type isn't hashable, and therefore `list` objects cannot be used as keys in a dictionary.

Comment: I recommend looking into the Pandas package.

Comment: Group is a integer variable as per you code its a temperature  , you may have to check city in dictionary cities_per_temp_bin  . Attach CSV or firsr 2 lines of CSV for us to modify your code

Comment: Please add some lines of your CSV file to your question so we can copy/paste and test your code

Comment: have you tried a nested dictionary hierarchy?